# Volume Slider within SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, mpvolumeview

How do you get a volume slider working in SwiftUI. Apple's tutorials provide help in regards to incorporating UIKit into a SwiftUI view (https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views#create-a-custom-image-view) but nothing that I can find on the volume slider. Below is the code I've got to this point largely taken from my Storyboard slider and adjusted, but it's not producing anything.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

struct VolumeView: UIViewRepresentable {


    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        UIView(frame: .init(x: 50, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        setupVolumeSlider()
    }


    func setupVolumeSlider() {
        var mpVolumeSlider: UISlider?
        let volumeParentView: UIView! = UIView()
        for subview in MPVolumeView().subviews {
            guard let volumeSlider = subview as? UISlider else { continue }
            mpVolumeSlider = volumeSlider
        }

        guard mpVolumeSlider != nil else { return }
        volumeParentView.addSubview(mpVolumeSlider!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

A lot easier than I was making it out to be in the end:

```
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer
import UIKit

struct HomeView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MPVolumeView {
        MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MPVolumeView, context: Context) {

        }

}
```

Comment: Just a note that this will not show up in the preview window. I didn't test the simulator, but I suspect you need a physical device